# Unable to access remote website with SSH tunnel. Local port forwarding not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

What I'm trying to do is for learning purpose only and I'd need some help understanding as where and what is going wrong with the SSH tunnel that I created for accessing a remote website. Here is the setup:

1. SSH server is running on Raspberry Pi, which is on my local network and behind the   router. `IP: 192.168.1.3`
2. Laptop, which is going to make connection to SSH server and a tunnel to access a remote website. `IP: 192.168.1.6`

Process:

1. Connect to SSH server with following command:
   `ssh -L 2000:www.ibm.com:80 -i ~/.ssh/RaspberryPi ubuntu@192.168.1.3`
2. Key in `localhost:2000` in browser to get the webpage

Per my understanding, when `localhost:2000` in entered in a browser, `www.ibm.com` webpage should show up. However, I get a page with message `The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.` shows up.

Not sure, what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

Just take into account that are more things involved in connect to an url like redirections, http vs https and son on.

Try with another server. For example:

`ssh -L 2000:ip-api.com:80 -i ~/.ssh/RaspberryPi ubuntu@192.168.1.3`

and browse to `localhost:2000` or `localhost:2000/json/24.48.0.1`

Comment: @Franciso, Thank you for your inputs. It worked with `localhost:2000` and the server you mentioned `ip-api.com`